# How to find basis for ker$(T)$ for $T:P_n(R)\rightarrow P_n(R)$ given by differentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

In my opinion for polynomial $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$, only the constant term gets mapped to $0$, so the basis for Ker$(T)$ should be the constant term. But the answer states that the desired form should be $\{1,x,...,x^n\}$. What does the desired form mean?

Comment: One basis is the constant function $x \mapsto 1$. Not a huge amount of choice there (other than non zero scalar multiples).

Comment: kernel is when T(p(x))=0 that is when p(x) is a constant polynomial. so kernel has 0 and constants in it. basis for the nullspace=kernel is $\{ 1 \}$. The kernel has dim one from dimension theorem too.